# PowerBI: How do I convert a column with HTML to text while applying the HTML code?

Tags: html, powerbi

I have 4 columns, and one of the columns contains an HTML code. I want to convert that code into text while applying the HTML code (such as line breaks and bullet points). While looking online, I only see a solution by getting rid of the coding language, but this does not actually apply the code. The external plugins I see forms its own output for HTML, which is not what I want.

For a visual example:

I want to convert this:

Col 1 | Col 2 | **Col 3 with HTML** | Col 4

into this:

Col 1 | Col 2 | **Col 3 w/ applied HTML** | Col 4

Comment: is this what you're looking for ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/html-table

Comment: @Juan that's what I initially tried but it just removes my bullet points; doesn't apply them